# Running playwright test in Ubuntu returns errors that don't occur in Windows

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, testing, playwright

I have developed a test that runs fine both headless and headed in Windows. However, when I try the same test in Ubuntu (without GUI, headless) some elements aren't found and the test gets stuck. Any ideas on where to look? I only have little experience with Linux.

The error:

```
    locator.fill: Target closed
    =========================== logs ===========================
    waiting for selector "[placeholder="Subject\*"]"
    ============================================================

  69 |     await page
  70 |       .locator('[placeholder="Subject\\*"]')
> 71 |       .fill(`${Title}`);
     |        ^
```

UPDATE: As it turned out, the test was fine. The server it ran on was not. The pages were loading so slow (minutes to load a single page), that it looked like they were not loading at all, until timeout stopped the test. Upgrading the server resolved the issue.

Comment: Did you try using a wait? something like `waitForElementState('editable', 30000)`;

Comment: Hi @Raju, thanks for your reply. I haven't, but there's auto-waiting in playwright. It does wait, until the global timeout stops the test. The problem is that it only does that in Ubuntu, in Windows it works just fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.